# No se crean las tablas, usando spring, hibernate y jpa

Tags: java, xml

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en eclipse con el framework spring usando varias tecnologias, principalmente hibernate y jpa pero no logro hacer que se creen las tablas en la base de datos y no logro darme cuenta debido a que no puedo hacer la persistencia de los objetos si estos no existen. Lo estoy trabajando con maven y la verdad nose si es que me falta alguna dependencia o que otra cosa; y estoy usando un modelo de DAO generico y tambien las anotaciones para mapear las clases para "crear" supuestamente las relaciones para las tablas. Si alguno me pueda decir aunque sea que tengo un ";" se lo agradeceria.

este es el archivo de persistencia donde hago la conexion con la base de datos

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="unidad">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>model.Usuario</class>
    <class>model.Template</class>
    <class>model.Publicacion</class>
    <class>model.NotificacionCartelera</class>
    <class>model.Media</class>
    <class>model.Comentario</class>
    <class>model.Cartelera</class> 
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"    value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grupo18"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

este es el archivo web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"           xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>Spring MVC</display-name>
<listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

este el el xml del contexto de la aplicacion

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">
        <!-- Habilitamos configuración basada en anotaciones -->
        <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="spring" />
        <!--<context:component-scan base-package="ttps.daosjpa" /> -->
        <!--<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" 
            /> -->
        <!-- DataSource -->
        <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <!-- <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/> sin usan 
                .properties -->
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grupo18" />
            <property name="user" value="root" />

            <property name="minPoolSize" value="20" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
            <property name="maxIdleTime" value="600" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="emf"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="spring.model" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <!-- Manejador de Transacciones -->
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
        </bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    </beans>
```

este es un ejemplo de una clase

```
package model;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name="cartelera")
public class Cartelera {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    private String tipo;

    @ManyToMany
     private Collection<Template> templates;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "cartelera", cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Collection<Publicacion> publicaciones;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cartelera")
    private Collection<NotificacionCartelera> notificacion;

    private String descripcion;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "carteleras")
    private Collection<Usuario> usuarios;

    public Cartelera(String tipo, String descripcion) {
        super();
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public Cartelera(){

    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public Collection<Usuario> getUsuarios() {
        return usuarios;
    }

    public void setAlumnos(Collection<Usuario> usuarios) {
        this.usuarios = usuarios;
    }

    public Collection<Publicacion> getPublicaciones() {
        return publicaciones;
    }

    public void setPublicaciones(Collection<Publicacion> publicaciones) {
        this.publicaciones = publicaciones;
    }
}
```

Comment: Y qué error te sale?

Comment: ¿donde estas indicando en la configuracion de hibernate como mapear las clases? Quizas esta pagina te venga bien para ver como se pone la configuración [mapeado con anotacion](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/maven-3-hibernate-3-6-oracle-11g-example-annotation/)